# cqlsh can't connect to cassandra server

Tags: ubuntu, updates

happened after system update, before worked as expected. The server is local (no internet required to connect). Ubuntu

How to debug?

The error:

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})

the issue pretty much like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850
While it's marked as resolved, I still see it.

cassandra -v

3.7

cqlsh --version

cqlsh 5.0.1

python --version

Python 2.7.12

Comment: an edit, which would be appreciate, to add 'cassandra' tag. Can't do it on my own since cassandra is not on the list and I do not have enough reputation to add new tags

Answer (score 4):

To sum up the mentioned JIRA ticket for those who found this answer via Google like me:

1. This issue should be resolved for versions 2.1.16, 2.2.8, 3.0.9, 3.8 and installing those once they are released should solve the problem
2. One of the other solutions is to downgrade python from 2.7.12 to 2.7.11, because 2.7.12 introduced the breaking change
3. Another mentioned solution is to install the latest driver and use it instead of the bundled one:

   ```
   sudo pip install cassandra-driver
   export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE
   ```

The third solution worked well for me.

Comment: Somehow it worked for me after using method 3. Thanks!